# Spring Profiles Deprecated

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties

How to use inheritance in application.yml settings now?
I have updated to Spring Boot 2.6.7 and notice

**spring.profiles** is Deprecated

What changes should I make?

```
...

---

spring:
  profiles:   <--- Deprecated
    default:
      - "actuator"
      - "swagger"
    group:
      default:
        - "actuator"
        - "swagger"
      local:
        - "local"
        - "actuator"
        - "logger"
        - "swagger"
      staging:
        - "staging"
        - "actuator"
        - "logger"
        - "swagger"
      integration:
        - "integration"
```